# Robot Framework: "Argument got value that cannot be converted to None"

Tags: pycharm, robotframework, ui-automation, browser-automation

Has anybody run into this problem? I have a test that is working just fine, and I was adding the DataDriver Library for Robot Framework inside of PyCharm. I decided to go a different direction with my tests. When I came back to run them again, I got this error message.

```
python -m robot -t "Logins" Logins.robot
==============================================================================
PRCLogins :: Login tests                                  
==============================================================================
Logins                                                           | FAIL |
ValueError: Argument 'url' got value 'https://<URL>' that cannot be converted to None.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PRCLogins :: Login tests                                              | FAIL |
1 test, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Automation\TestSuite\output.xml
Log:     C:\Automation\TestSuite\log.html
Report:  C:\Automation\TestSuite\report.html

Process finished with exit code 1
```

And now, NONE of my tests will run. Not even the tests that had nothing to do with this test suite. I'm fully blocked somehow and now cannot run ANY of my tests. Has anybody seen this error before? Please help!

Comment: I don't use robotframework but you should try to understand how exactly the test configuration files should be written.

Comment: Error says `Argument 'url' got value 'https://<URL>' `.. is the `<URL>` your modification or an actual string in your test data ?

Comment: From here we can only guess what is problem. Try open C:\Automation\TestSuite\log.html and change log level to "Trace" and see what keywords are call and its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Robot framework does automatic conversion of arguments to the types that are annotated in keyword function definitions.

```py
@keyword
def the_keyword_name(self, the_argument: float):
    ...
```

For the example above - robot will try to convert `the_argument` into `float` before executing the keyword code. In your case - you need to correct the type annotation.